# How do I prepend a character to a field in a csv using awk

Tags: csv, awk

I am trying to prepend a single character to the beginning of a quoted csv file that looks like this:

```
"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"
```

The output I need would look like this:

```
"a","b","c","d","e","Nf","g","h"
```

Using the following awk command:

```
awk -F '{ $6="N" $6 }1' file.csv
```

I get the following close, but incorrect result:

```
"a","b","c","d","e",N"f","g","h"
```

How do I write an `awk` command that will correctly prepend a character inside the quoted text of a given field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **`awk`**'s `sub()` function:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }{ sub(/"/, "&N", $6) }1' file.csv
```

The output:

```
"a","b","c","d","e","Nf","g","h"
```

---

Or with `substr()` function:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }{ $6="\042N"substr($6, 2) }1' file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\",\""} {$6="N"$6} 1' file
"a","b","c","d","e","Nf","g","h"
```

Answer (score 1):

with GNU `sed`

```
$ sed 's/,"/,"N/5' file

"a","b","c","d","e","Nf","g","h"
```

do the replacement after 5th comma, that is 6th field.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` one liner

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/"/,"\"N",$6)}1' f1
"a","b","c","d","e","Nf","g","h"
```